# Installing RoR stack on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, lamp

I just got a new MacBook Pro and would like to install / upgrade the the Ruby on Rails stack specifically. My question is whether I should **sudo** all the installs / upgrades. The usual suspects of what I plan to install / upgrade are: Ruby, Gems, Rails, MySQL, sqlite3, PostgreSQL, RVM, Nginx, Passenger. I understand that RVM can be installed with different levels of access, root vs admin user, etc. Anyone knows what's the preferred way of installing RVM?

**UPDATE**
I know that LAMP isn't RoR, I just thought it was more inclusive seeing that it included web server, database, etc. Anyway, my bad, I have removed it from the post to avoid confusion. I have installed all the various components before, so this isn't a question about how to install them, this is a question about if I should install them as root or just the usual admin user.

Comment: LAMP: Linux Apache MySQL and PHP; Clearly you aren't actually interested in installing this 'stack'.

Answer (score 2):

Apache comes installed; edit the configuration file here: `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. To start/stop apache, open your System Prefrences.app, go to Sharing, and click the checkbox next to Web Sharing.

For MySQL, simply download the dmg and install http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

sqlite3 comines installed

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx

How to install RVM: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Update your ruby gems: `sudo gem update --system`

Update rails: `gem update rails`

Bonus: Awesome package manager for MacOS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew. You don't actually need this for the things you listed above, but I would highly recommend this if you plan on compiling/installing any additional packages on your system. (You'll need to install Xcode for this.)

---

PS: You don't actually mean "LAMP" as the P stands for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but the same concept applies. Excellent tutorial on how to do what you're asking for the best way.

[Hivelogic Tutorial](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard)